# Manipulation of Google Form data into one record

Tags: google-apps-script

I am designing a service hour record system for a docent service. The user inputs the applier's name, date of activity, number of service hours, and the registration number of all docents participated (separated by commas).

What I want to do is to make one record of all docents and all the activities they have participated. The registration numbers of the entries are split and transposed into one column in another sheet, the details of the activity are copied onto the same sheet, then the details of the docent are taken from a name list and pasted. I would like to ask if there's any way I can automate this process through a function by google apps script?

Included is a sample file with 3 entries, the name list called 'Database' and the intended just in case you don't understand what I wanted.

[This is the link to my file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PIEBkw-7wIeqAC-bR8jwzOz2AtoWaynAKdggQMBrqeo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to use the [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started) provided by AppScript since you put your data into CSV files. To manipulate data from your docent system, you'll need to learn how to [import and export from your CSV file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section-2-importing-data-from-a-csv-file) too.